# Beautiful Soup is not selecting any element

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-3.5, beautifulsoup

This is the code I am using to iterate over all elements:

```
soup_top = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r_top.text, 'html.parser')

selector = '#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDisplay table tr td:nth-of-type(3) a'

for link in soup_top.select(selector):
    print(link)
```

The same selector gives a length of 57 when used in JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDisplay table tr td:nth-of-type(3) a").length;
```

I thought that maybe I am not getting the contents of the webpage correctly. I then saved a local copy of the webpage but the selector in Beautiful Soup still did not select anything. What is going on here?

This is the [website](http://www.swapnilpatni.com/law_charts_final.php) I am using the code on.

Comment: Could you share the HTML? Without it, it's going to be rather hard to see what's going on.

Comment: As already mentioned, we have no idea without seeing the html

Comment: @Kristof I have added a link to the website, I am trying to scrape.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have added the link to the website. I can't share the HTML directly in the code because it is pretty complex with tables inside tables.

Comment: I need to select all the download buttons using bs4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is due to the [parser](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-a-parser) you used (i.e. `html.parser`). If I try the same thing with `lxml` as parser:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.swapnilpatni.com/law_charts_final.php'
r = requests.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

css_select = '#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDisplay table tr td:nth-of-type(3) a'
links = soup.select(css_select)
print('{} link(s) found'.format(len(links)))

>> 1 link(s) found

for link in links:
    print(link['href'])

>> spadmin/doc/Company Law amendment 1.1.png
```

The `html.parser` will return a result up until `#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDisplay table tr`, and even then it only returns the first `tr`.

When running the url through [W3 Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org), this is the error that is returned:

> Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 1212 it contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.
>   The error was: utf8 "\xA0" does not map to Unicode

It's likely that the `html.parser` chokes on this as well, while `lxml` is more fault-tolerant.

Comment: Thanks kristof :)

Is it generally better to use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`?

Comment: Well as you can see in the comparison table in the docs, `lxml` is fast (as it's written in C) and very lenient. Personally, I always use `lxml` but the downside is that it introduces an additional external dependancy into your project.

Comment: I got the error `Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml`. I guess this is what you meant by external dependency. How to I resolve it?

Comment: You have to install `lxml` first (e.g. `pip install lxml`) just like you would with any external library.

Comment: Thanks again kristof. I would never have thought that the error was because of the parser.